# Printf 's Param

Tags: c, printf, param

I find this code , see, the printf has only one param.And, it work! All I kown about printf is printf("format",...);  but why this code work? Any answer will help . Thanks.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3 int main()
  4 {
  5         char a[]= "hello world";
  6         printf(a);
  7         return 0;
  8 }
~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is the format. However, this kind of usage is very dangerous because lots of people forget that `a` is a format and instead think it's a literal string. The difference is that, if `a` happened to contain `%`, it would be interpreted as a format specifier, but you have no arguments for to specifier to go with.

When printing a single message string with `printf`, you should always instead do:

```
printf("%s", a);
```

Or just use `puts` if appropriate.

Comment: @R.. I know printf("%s",a); I am confused about printf(a), I think it will never across compile :) .Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

`a` is being treated as a format string that contains no format specifiers.

Normally, `printf()` will scan the format string, print anything that isn't a format specifier. When it encounters a specifier, it decodes it, then takes an argument from the variable argument list, formats it according to the specifier, and outputs that, then continues like that in a loop until it reaches the end of the string.

Since `a` contains no format specifiers, `printf()` takes no arguments from the variable argument list.

Generally speaking, `printf()` should not be used to print arbitrary strings in this way. If the program is only printing a string, you can use `fputs()` instead:

```
fputs(a, stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf` is a function with variable list of parameters.  The first parameter is a string that is parsed to find the formatting details.  In the example you gave, there is no formatting detail (fields starting with `%`).  Hence, there is no more parameters to be printed and the code works.

Answer (score 0):

`int printf ( const char * format, ... );`

Is a function with a required argument, `format` and a list argument that can be a list or zero or more elements, represented by `...`.

Thus, `printf(a);` is simply a call to `printf()` with only the required argument.